# Mongo DB Scalability

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

My Node JS application with Mongoose and MongoDB receives about 15,000-45,000 posts a day.

Each of these posts is a separate document in Mongo DB.

Which example is better for the longevity and scalability of the application in regards to the way the data is structured:

1. Storing all posts under a single collection named 'posts' giving every post document a {date: TODAY's DATE, post-content: content}

or

2. Create a new collection for every day of posts. Ex: Posts.6-29-2019 and store every post from that day in that one collection.

What will be more costly in the long term:

Searching through essentially millions of posts after a year of data with all posts in a single collection?

Or

Storing essentially hundreds of thousands of collections of posts from each day?

Comment: "hundreds of thousands of collections" - Not sure how it is now, but mongodb used to have limited namespace size. Meaning _you can run out of collections_.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The WiredTiger storage engine doesn't have a set limit on the number of collections you can have. However, there is a practical (hardware) limit, since each collection and index is a file. You can overwhelm your hardware with too many open files. Example: [SERVER-25025](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25025)

Answer (score 0):

> Searching through essentially millions of posts after a year of data with all posts in a single collection?

Fullscans are bad, but good news is: you can avoid them in most cases. Just add proper indexes to support your queries.

Comment: You're suggesting to put all millions of posts in one collection rather than multiple collections by date?

Comment: @user10181542: exactly.

Comment: How do you suggest to index them? var blogSchema = new Schema({
    date:  Date,
    content: [{ body: String }],
  });

Comment: I must also point out, I need to be able to retrieve how many posts were made in a single day or how many have been made so far today, very quickly.

Comment: @user10181542: that's a separate discussion entirely (what are proper indexes in a given situation). But to address query performance schema changes and/or indexes are normally used. Not manually partitioning your data.

Comment: @user10181542: think about it: if you need to search through your whole dataset, you need to search through your whole dataset. Hardware requirements are more or less the same, only with the second approach, the code is 30x more complex.